# Password-less File transfer using RCP and Expect

Tags: unix, expect, rcp

I have a requirement to transfer files from one server to another. I used RCP command to perform the same and it was working fine. Please find code below:

```
rcp tst.txt usrname@hostname:/home/username/destination_folder
```

I tried to automate the same using Expect command so created the below mentioned shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect -d<<EOD
spawn rcp tst.txt usrname@hostname:/home/username/destination_folder
expect "*userid@hostname's password:*"
send "mypassword\n"
EOD
```

I didn't get any error while I executing the shell script but the file was not transferred. Can someone help me figuring out what the issue is?

I have tried password less transfer through key generation but with no luck so I am trying the RCP approach.

Thanks in Advance,
Vijay

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `rcp`?  That command has been obsolete for years -- it isn't even included in most modern OS versions and distros. `scp` would be a better option if it's available, and you can set up keys to avoid the need to use expect for passwords at all. [I'd prefer not to suggest ways to implement an inferior solution.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sending the password, wait for the completion of `rcp`, by expecting for `eof`.

```
send "mypassword\r"
expect eof
```

If password-less, then, after spawning `rcp`, expect for `eof`.

Comment: Instead of `\n`, use `\r`.

Comment: Worked like a charm!!Thanks a ton for helping me out. There was lots of pressure on me to  complete the script and transfer the file as there are other applications waiting for the data. I understand that key generation is the way to go but could not explore it in detail due to lack of time. Can't Thank you enough for helping me out.